# How to set left top position for siblings from parent in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, my html code,

```
<ul>
  <!-- Group1 -->
  <li class="a1 mainParent"><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="a1 child-up" style="left:0; top:-68px"><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li class="a1 child-up" style="left:0; top:-34px"><a href="#">12</a></li>
  <li class="a1 child-down" style="left:0; top:34px"><a href="#">13</a></li>
  <li class="a1 child-down" style="left:0; top:68px"><a href="#">14</a></li>

  <!-- Group2 -->
  <li class="a2 mainParent"><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="a2 child-up" style="left:68px; top:-68px"><a href="#">21</a></li>
  <li class="a2 child-up" style="left:68px; top:-34px"><a href="#">22</a></li>
  <li class="a2 child-down" style="left:68px; top:34px"><a href="#">23</a></li>
  <li class="a2 child-down" style="left:68px; top:68px"><a href="#">24</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now i wrote left and top position an inline. How can i achieve this functionality with jquery?

Not only two groups it will append more groups in future. But this html structure will never change.

**Output structure:**

[image]

Comment: Just a question...Is there a specific reason why the `left` of Group1 and Group2 differ?

Comment: Yes. it will display like a tree structure.

Comment: So then, `a2` is a child of `a1`...?

Comment: No. a1 is a one parent and a2 is an another parent item.

Comment: Sorry to be asking so many questions but, then I don't understand why `a1` and `a2` have different value of `left` for the tree structure indentation. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AhsN It really doesn't matter why it is written like that. He wants an answer (which he got and which will function). Why he is writing his HTML like that or what the final product must look like is not relevant.

Comment: @AhsN, I have uploaded output image.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it with jQuery, when you can do it with CSS?

```
.a1.mainparent div[class^="child-"] {
   left: 0;
}

.a2.mainparent div[class^="child-"] {
   left: 68px;
}

/*etc*/
```

The `class^` is a wildcard that means "any class starting with". You can also use `class*`, which means "any class containing", but in your case you might as well use `class^`.

Comment: What when the user "_will append more groups in future_"...?

Comment: Well, no matter if he uses jQuery or CSS, he'll have to manually add a new line for every new group, since he uses different values on `left` for each group.